# Rails: efficiently check if keywords in a model match content in another model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, associations, models, has-and-belongs-to-many

How can I efficiently check several thousand rows against a table of keywords?

I have two tables, **Essays** and **Tags**. They are tied together by a **has_and_belongs_to_many** association.

**Tags** has around 250 keywords (rows) and several thousand **essays** are added every day.

I want to scan the **essay** subject and content against the keywords in the **Tags** table and if there is a match, associate the Tag with the essay

What would be the most efficient way to do this?

Is there any way of doing this aside from iterating through each essay and then regex matching the content against all of the tag keywords?

Comment: If your regexes are constant (i.e., they're just tags, no regex metacharacters), you can at least start by using `String#include?` instead of regular expressions. :-)

Comment: I'm pretty sure iteration is the only way here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking at getting drastic performance improvement then my suggestion would be to go with some sort of indexing system like ultrasphinx.

https://github.com/fauna/ultrasphinx

Another good option is using acts_as_indexed plugin:

http://douglasfshearer.com/blog/rails-plugin-acts_as_indexed